# Verify signature on a file nodejs

Tags: node.js, cryptography, public-key-encryption, verification

I don't understand why verify always returns false for me... running openssl will return that everything is just dandy

```
$ openssl dgst -md5 -verify mykey.pub -signature signature message.txt
Verified OK
```

However, running my code in the node results in the verification to be false

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var crypto = require('crypto');

//pass in arguments
var args = process.argv.slice(2);
fs.readFile(args[0], 'ascii', function(err,signature){
    if(err){console.log(err);}
    fs.readFile(args[1], 'ascii', function(err,message){
        if(err){console.log(err);}
        fs.readFile(args[2], 'ascii', function(err,publickey){
            if(err){console.log(err);}
            verify(signature, message, publickey);
        });
    });
});

//verify function
var verify = function(signature, message, publickey){
    //everything prints out right
    console.log(signature.toString() + '\n');
    console.log(message.toString() + '\n');
    console.log(publickey.toString() + '\n');

    //using md5
    var verifier = crypto.createVerify('md5');

    verifier.update(message.toString());
    var WHAT = verifier.verify(publickey.toString(), signature.toString(), 'binary');
    console.log(WHAT);
};
```

Looking at the output results in this

```
$ node verifyHash signature message.txt mykey.pub
B`⌂ pgfs☼st;3_V1I☻l♂[V5 =C♠~o▲§►rH`KZ7#♦♠LiQ⌂xFw
▼♣"↓d;.H4+↕$WZF▲◄Ow▲r⌂,
j]U↕6►vQm$7v&^^uF↨/ma2F→*n
►¶o'$jN!☼↑☺aV+↔e^qH▲A►rmx.

HEllo

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDDgn0PrHxivu0zgG8pp66yMwxJ
MyYsdocVNpZ+673WlRlN0NKQRkI7+F7rYMG4KWL0pDBeOahOggxNVTNV9cxkCKce
Gp37+ZED5HiHKDll4tVoGVSDLaW0BBVe1TzfJSS64fvN/OssyjKffD5ExpLE4O5o
Vv7robQ0JxzYfbz2FQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: tried toString() all the variables, no luck

Comment: Your snippet looks OK at a glance, so my next suspicion is your `...` code contains some mistake with the `fs` module or encoding or something along those lines. Can you post a complete program including the code you have to load data from the filesystem?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/E2J6Wjii

there you go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot read the signature as ASCII, as it contains binary data (byte values > 128). These will get stripped then [1].

As the verifier is a [`stream.Writable`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) the easiest solution is to use [`fs.createReadStream`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) and then [`pipe`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) to pipe it into the verifier.

See this REPL transcript:

```
> crypto = require('crypto'); undefined
undefined
> fs = require('fs'); undefined
undefined
> verifier = crypto.createVerify('md5'); undefined
undefined
> fs.createReadStream('file').pipe(verifier); undefined
undefined
> verifier.verify(fs.readFileSync('publickey.pem'), fs.readFileSync('signature.sign'), 'binary');
true
```

[1]

```
> new Buffer(fs.readFileSync('signature.sign', 'binary')).toString('hex');
'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'
> new Buffer(fs.readFileSync('signature.sign', 'ascii')).toString('hex');
'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'
```

Comment: This code gives me an error for some reason, but I just replaced my code with your 

verifier.verify(fs.readFileSync('publickey.pem'), fs.readFileSync('signature.sign')

and it works like a charm. Thanks so much!

Comment: @OuwenHuang You should not use the `Sync` versions if you are dealing with user interactions, as they block the event loop from executing. My `pipe` example left out handling the `end` event. Maybe the data was not fully consumed yet when you tried it in a non interactive script, leading to failure: http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to use Windows/macOS npm package util **sign-check** for executables/files signature verification.

It uses built-in OS mechanisms to verify is code signed (`codesign --verify` command for macOS and WinVerifyTrust API implementation for Windows).

For sign verification you can just use:

```
const SignCheck = require('sign-check');     
const somePath = 'some/path/for/test';

SignCheck.checkMac(somePath).then(
    (isSigned) => {
        console.log('File sign status ' + isSigned);
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

Or `checkWin` function for Windows platform.

Comment: Hi kami4ka, welcome to SO. Providing some code would improve your answer significantly.